# Can we show only suggestion OTP above keyboard and hide keyboard section in Swift/IOS

Tags: ios, swift

We need to achieve functionality where user can not type OTP manually , so we don't want to give user an option to enter OTP , rather we want to use one tap feature of keyboard from IOS 12 , where user can tap on suggestion displayed over keyboard and OTP filled automatically . So can we hide keyboard but suggestion OTP still being displayed?

Comment: no, i dont think that you can do that

Comment: we want to disable/hide part of keyboard so that suggestion box still displayed, is it recommended by Apple ?

Comment: no it is not recommended by Apple, thats why theres no support for it